# Ordering activity bar items not working

Tags: android, menu

I have 4 items defined in xml as secondary then later I create one more in the code defined as container. I'm trying to get the one created in code (share) to be first, it's not working. It is always added to the end of the menu. I was under the impression that the menu category is what decided the action bar order. What am I missing?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_unlock"
          android:menuCategory="secondary"
          android:title="Unlock"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
          android:menuCategory="secondary"
          android:title="Share App"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_follow"
          android:menuCategory="secondary"
          android:title="Follow"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_review"
          android:menuCategory="secondary"
          android:title="Review"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

```java
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    actions = menu;

    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


/*
 *  Set whether share buttons should be available.
 */
public void setShareable (boolean shareable)
{
    if (!shareable)
        return;

    // Build share button
    MenuItem item = actions.add (Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, Menu.CATEGORY_CONTAINER, "Share");
    item.setShowAsAction (MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
}
```

Comment: Why not use `android:orderInCategory` attribute instead, and then you could set the 'Share' item's order to a lower number?

Comment: That fixed it, put it in an answer and I'll accept it. But correct me if I'm wrong, shouldn't the way I had it have worked as well?

Comment: From the documentation: CATEGORY_CONTAINER: Category code for the order integer for items/groups that are part of a container -- or/add this with your base value.
Did you try CATEGORY_FIRST?

Comment: Did you try the CATEGORY_FIRST option as well? I'm curious to know how it works.

Comment: Setting the category as Menu.FIRST does work as well. (There is no CATEGORY_FIRST)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct usage of menu categories is to use `FIRST` instead of `CONTAINER` for the menu item that needs to get highest priority, and the rest as `SECONDARY` as used in the question.

An alternate way to order the menu items is through the `android:orderInCategory` attribute. Set the first preexisting menu item to, say, order 10 (even 2 would work in your case), and then you can add up to 9 other menu items before it, dynamically, by setting this attribute in the code (`menu.add(Menu.NONE,Menu.NONE, order,R.string.my_menu_item)`. The `order` variable here is a little tricky, since it's an `int` that represents both the group association and the order within that group: see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getOrder()).